# Remove LVM volume after failed disk, lvchange/vgchange/dmsetup not enough

Tags: linux, hard-drive, lvm

A disk hosting part of an LVM volume failed, I'm trying to unmount everything properly to run `btrfs check` on it. I've unmounted the BTRFS volume successfully but I can't do anything with the disk since everything I throw at it crashes with "Device or resource busy".

I tried deactivating the volume using `lvchange -a n` or `vgchange -a n`, same error.

After calling `dmsetup info`, I got `Number of targets: 4` (there are four disks). I ran `dmsetup remove`, got

```
device-mapper: remove ioctl on storage-storage  failed: Device or resource busy
Command failed.
```

Since then, `info` gives `Number of targets: 1`, which I guess means that it's unable to properly remove the failed disk, which makes sense.

Right now, I'm stuck. I don't know of anything stronger or lower-level than `dmsetup remove --force` apart from restarting the server which is currently not possible.

Comment: Have you disconnected the failed disk yet?

Comment: It sounds like you need to try and do block level recovery if the failed drive, then use the replacement drive.  (and doing anything else on a failing drive is a bad idea).  It is possible something is holding the drive open.  Are you able to add another block device while the host is online and use ddrescue to mirror it?